# R replace name element of df1 with name of other df2

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames, that present different `nrow`, `df1 nrow = 500`, `df2 nrow = 30`, but all the elements in the `df1$Taxa` are present in `rownames(df2)`

`df1[1:5, ]`

```
   Taxa  Env Correlation     Pvalue Type AdjPvalue Significance
1 C1414   pH -0.44448524 0.01570246    T 0.2774101             
2 C305   pH -0.03514715 0.80462576    V 0.8953632             
3 C6066 Temp -0.26652662 0.16223749    T 0.7098855             
4 C4483 Temp -0.24711638 0.07736761    V 0.7098855             
5 C1161   TS  0.04660032 0.81029772    T 0.8793111
```

`df2[1:5, ]`

```
        Domain         Phylum
C1414 Bacteria Actinobacteria
C305  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes
C6066 Bacteria       Chlorobi
C4483 Bacteria  Fibrobacteres
C1161 Bacteria  Firmicutes
```

So I want to make a replace each element name of the Taxa column in the df1, with the Phylum column of the df2, something like:

`df3`:

```
             Taxa  Env Correlation     Pvalue    Type AdjPvalue Significance
1 Actinobacteria   pH    -0.44448524 0.01570246    T 0.2774101             
2 Bacteroidetes    pH    -0.03514715 0.80462576    V 0.8953632             
3 Chlorobi         Temp  -0.26652662 0.16223749    T 0.7098855             
4 Fibrobacteres    Temp  -0.24711638 0.07736761    V 0.7098855             
5 Firmicutes       TS     0.04660032 0.81029772    T 0.8793111
```

I have tried `cbind`, but the problem is the `nrow` in `df1  cbind(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `match`

```
df1$Taxa <- df2$Phylum[match(df1$Taxa, row.names(df2))]
df1$Taxa
#[1] "Actinobacteria" "Bacteroidetes"  "Chlorobi"       "Fibrobacteres"  "Firmicutes"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Taxa = c("C1414", "C305", "C6066", "C4483", "C1161"
), Env = c("pH", "pH", "Temp", "Temp", "TS"), Correlation = c(-0.44448524, 
-0.03514715, -0.26652662, -0.24711638, 0.04660032), Pvalue = c(0.01570246, 
0.80462576, 0.16223749, 0.07736761, 0.81029772), Type = c("T", 
"V", "T", "V", "T"), AdjPvalueSignificance = c(0.2774101, 0.8953632, 
0.7098855, 0.7098855, 0.8793111)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(Domain = c("Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", 
"Bacteria", "Bacteria"), Phylum = c("Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", 
"Chlorobi", "Fibrobacteres", "Firmicutes")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("C1414", 
"C305", "C6066", "C4483", "C1161"))
```